# Default values on request of variable

Tags: php, forms

I have one form as below in test1.php

```
<form action="test.php?CID=25" name="form1" METHOD="POST">
    <input type=text name="YID" VALUE="22" />
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

test.php file will request the variable CID and YID.

in classic asp I can request both variable like below.

```
CID=REQUEST("CID")
YID=REQUEST("YID")
```

REQUEST will work for both. 
As CID is a variable which will appear in the hyperlink as below

```
http://localhost/test.php?CID=25
```

on submitting the form in test1.php.

in classic asp if any variable is not defined then I can handle the variable as below.

```
CID=REQUEST("CID"):if isnull(CID) or trim(CID)="" then CID=0
YID=REQUEST("YID"):if isnull(YID) or trim(YID)="" then YID=0
```

How could it be done in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this URL:

```
http://localhost/test.php?CID=25
```

If you want the value of CID you would use:

```
$_GET['CID']
```

From a POSTed form containing:

```
<input type=text name="YID" VALUE="22" />
```

You would use

```
$_POST['YID']
```

If you need to test if a veriable is set you can use

```
$value = isset($_POST['YID']) ? $_POST['YID'] : '';
```

This is shorthand for

```
if(isset($_POST['YID'])){
  $value = $_POST['YID'];
} else {
  $value = 0; // or FALSE or null or '' or any default value you want
}
```

Comment: what if CID is posted from test2.php file. Can it be possible to handle both with $_request[]. and what is CID is not possed at all.

Comment: It doesn't matter which file the request originated from. The script that responds to the request has access to the $_GET and $_POST values contained in the request. $_REQUEST will work (if it's enabled I think) but I have never needed to use it myself. I edited my response for unset variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have used the code $YID=isset($_REQUEST['YID'])?$_REQUEST['YID']:0;  which take care of both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$_REQUEST['CID']==null ? ($CID=0) : ($CID=$_REQUEST['CID']);
```

or this can be used-

```
function getIfSet(&$value, $default = 0)
{
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}

$CID = getIfSet($_REQUEST["CID"]);
```

Comment: This will work but it will throw a notice if $_REQUEST['CID'] is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $CID = (isset($_GET['CID']) and $_GET['CID'] != '') ? $_GET['CID'] : 0;
  $YID = (isset($_POST['YID']) and $_POST['YID'] != '') ? $_POST['YID'] : 0;
```